# Advantage Of ECDH-RSA over RSA Ciphersuites In TLS

Tags: tls, rsa, key-exchange, diffie-hellman, ecc

If `ECDH-RSA` is used for key exchange, this is what happens:

The server has its public `ECDH` parameter embedded within its certificate. The client generates its public `ECDH` parameter, extracts the server's public `ECDH` parameter and generates the shared `ECDH` secret. This secret is then used as the premaster secret.

---

If `RSA` key exchange is used, this is what happens:

The server has its public key embedded within its certificate. The client generates the premaster secret, encrypts it with the server's public key and sends it to the server.

---

None of the ciphersuites offer Perfect Forward Secrecy, so what is the advantage of using an `ECDH-RSA`-based ciphersuite over an `RSA` one?

I did some evaluations, using **2048**-bit RSA keys and **256**-bit ECDH key. In the table below, I present the number of CPU instructions (in millions) used by the client and the server to perform the key exchange with each algorithm:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|        | RSA  | ECDH-RSA |
+--------+------+----------+
| Client |  4.5 |     54.5 |
| Server | 75.5 |     27.5 |
+--------+------+----------+
```

This means that in an `RSA` key exchange, the client uses 4.5 million CPU instructions, while the server uses 75.5 million CPU instructions. Similarly, in an `ECDH-RSA` key exchange, the client uses 54.5 million CPU instructions, while the server uses 27.5 million CPU instructions.

If we raise the security level to **7680**-bit RSA keys and **409**-bit ECDH keys, we obtain the following results:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|        | RSA  | ECDH-RSA |
+--------+------+----------+
| Client | 15.5 |     89.5 |
| Server | 1503 |     44.5 |
+--------+------+----------+
```

In `RSA`, the server-side cost raise abruptly. This can be explained by the fact that the server will use a very large private RSA key to decrypt the premaster secret. Note how now the server uses 1503 million (*i.e.* 1.5 billion) CPU cycles to perform an `RSA` key exchange.

Since no extra security is offered when `ECDH-RSA` is used, the main advantages that I could find are cost-related and do not benefit both parties:

- Total cost is a lot smaller when the security level is raised.
- Helps to "even the costs out", to minimize the resource usage differences between the peers.
- There is a smaller increase in total costs as the security level increases. This brings advantages to the server (specially for higher security levels).

The client is, however, always in a cost disadvantage when `ECDH-RSA` key exchange is used instead of `RSA`. Assuming that I'm a selfish user browsing the web, wouldn't it make more sense for me to always prefer the `RSA` key exchange?

Comment: A few million extra cycles isn't going to impact your browsing experience.